# Write to clipboard

Tags: vb6

VB6:
I am able to write to clipboard using Clipboard.SetText.
But I want to write in steps.
Like first String1.
Then append String2 after String1.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I there any way of writing to clipboard without taking it back to string?

Answer (score 4):

Rob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309942/write-to-clipboard/1309976#1309976) is good. My additional advice is to always use `Clipboard.Clear` before using `Clipboard.SetText`. Otherwise, the user might not be able to paste your text.

E.g. if the user first copies "text one" in Word, then uses your app to copy "text two", then uses Paste in Word: it will paste "text one". This happens because the [clipboard still contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013(VS.85).aspx) the formatted string "text one" from Word, and Word uses that formatted text in preference to your unformatted text.

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of what you've written to the clipboard with another string, which I'll call `ClipboardString`.

You can set `ClipboardString` equal to `String1`, then set the clipboard to `ClipboardString`. Then append `String2` to `ClipboardString` and set the clipboard to `ClipboardString`. And so on...

Doing it this way will eliminate any possible problems with other programs overwriting the clipboard before you're done appending your strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write your first bit, then later read the clipboard and append to what you read and set the text again...the only issue is that some other app might write to the clipboard during this time.